# Receiving success response but the button still disabled using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am checking email id is available or not in the database using ajax which is working.I have one submit button and that is disabled on page load.I have to enable that button when the user enters the right email address which is available on the database. If email is available in the database the button will enable otherwise button will be disabled.There is some issue in if condition. I tried button still the same issue. Would you help me in this?

```
$("input[type='submit']").removeAttr("disabled");
    $("input[type='submit']").prop('disabled', false);
```

If I used CSS for button then disable is not working.

**Html**

```
 <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="text_field" />
<span id="email-validation-error" class="error"></span> 
<input id="id" type="submit" name="next" value="submit"  >
```

**Ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
    $("input[name='email']").on('keyup',function()
       {
        var email = $('#email').val();
        $.ajax(
        {
            url:'process.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:'email='+email,
             success:function(data)
            {
              if (data == 1) {
            $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled' , false);
              }
              else{
                $("#email-validation-error").html(data);
                $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true);
              }
            },
        });
    });
});

//Disable the button on page load
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true);
    });
```

**Process.php**

```
include('db/connection.php');

if(isset($_POST['email'])){
$email=$_POST['email'];
$query="SELECT Email FROM `request` WHERE Email='".$email."'";
$result = $conn->query($query);

$search_record=$result->num_rows;

if ($search_record == 0) {
  echo "Email does not exist, please sign up to use our services";
  }
}
```

Comment: what issue do you get? your code seems fine? https://jsfiddle.net/maddak7q/

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Mark. After enter email id submit button will active but I don't know why my code is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found my answer with the help of Mr.Ahmed Ginani

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title></title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<form >
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="text_field" /> 
<span id="email-validation-error" class="error"></span> 


<input id="id" type="submit" name="next" value="submit" disabled> 
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 


$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
var elem = $("#id"); //assign target element with id 
$(elem).attr('disabled', true); 
$("input[name='email']").bind('change',function() // Changes from key press to change and bind
{ 
var email = $('#email').val(); 
$.ajax( 
{ 
url:'process.php', 
type:'POST', 
data:'email='+email, 
success:function(data) 
{ 
if (data == 'success') { // getting success name from process.php page
$("#id").attr('disabled' , false); 
$("#email-validation-error").html(''); //Change here for hiding the error message
} 
else{ 
$("#email-validation-error").html(data); 
$('#id').attr('disabled', true); 
} 
}, 
}); 
}); 
}); 

</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

**Process.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
$email=$_POST['email'];
$_SESSION['username']=$email;

$query="SELECT Email FROM `request` WHERE Email='".$email."'";
$result = $conn->query($query);

$search_record=$result->num_rows;

if ($search_record > 0) {
    echo "success";
      }
    else{
     echo "Email does not exist, please sign up to use our services";
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
    var elem = $("#id");  //assign target element with id
    $("input[name='email']").on('keyup',function()
       {
        var email = $('#email').val();
        $.ajax(
        {
            url:'process.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:'email='+email,
             success:function(data)
            {
              if (data == "ok") {
            $(elem).attr('disabled' , false); //here pass elem
              }
              else{
                $("#email-validation-error").html('Email not available');
                $(elem).attr('disabled', true);  //here pass elem
              }
            },
        });
    });
});
```

**Process.php**

```
include('db/connection.php');

    if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $query="SELECT Email FROM `request` WHERE Email='".$email."'";
    $result = $conn->query($query);

    $search_record=$result->num_rows;

    if ($search_record == 0) {
      echo "ok";
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying MR.Shubham715, I tried your code but still not working. I am entering correct email Id which is available in the database but my button is not enabling.

Comment: put a alert after if (data == 1) {  and check its working or not example if (data == 1) { alert("hello"); } if alert not come then you should check into console what response is coming.

Comment: Yes I haven't got any alert and console is showing empty

Comment: I entered the right email but it is showing "Email not available" If the condition is not working. It is checking only else part

Comment: I am disabling the button on page load. Is that code perfect?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146391/discussion-between-narendra-verma-and-shubham715).

Answer (score 0):

You should check and verify your response:

**Process.php**

```
  if ($search_record == 0) {
         echo "Email does not exist, please sign up to use our services";
      }
    else{
        echo "success";
    }
```

**Ajax**

```
if (data == "success") {
 $("#submitYesNo").prop('disabled', false);

 }
 else{
 $("#email-validation-error").html(data);
 $("#submitYesNo").prop('disabled', true);     
}
```

**html**

```
<input id="submitYesNo" type="submit" name="next" value="submit"  >
```

Comment: I am getting only Sucess message but the button is still disabled.

Comment: I am disabling the button on page load. Is that code perfect?

Comment: yes thats fine that was not issue can you try disable enable that button on simple click you will get proper idea about where is actual bug also try to alert message on success

Comment: are you getting any error or anything else in console log?

Comment: @NarendraVerma i have possible options that first check ajax is calling, are you getting data, then check enable disable i can't help without knowing actual error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146396/discussion-between-narendra-verma-and-ahmed-ginani).

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code .

Hope it will work properly

```
 success:function(data)
 {
    if (data == 1)
    {
        $('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
    else
    {
       $("#email-validation-error").html(data);
      $('input[type="submit"]').attr("disabled", "disabled");

    }
```

Comment: <input id="id" type="submit" name="next" value="submit"  disabled="disabled">

submit button add one more attribute disabled="disabled".

Comment: if ($search_record == 0) {
  echo "Email does not exist, please sign up to use our services";
  }
}

CHANGE IT:
if ($search_record == 0) {
  echo 1;
  }
}